# What is the dominant mechanism due to which laboratory plasma in the LTE model emits light

Tags: radiation, plasma-physics

I am studying plasma physics these days and I need a clarification about this question:

What is the dominant mechanism due to which laboratory plasma in LTE model emits light?

So a few words before the technical question:

In plasma physics, a less strict condition than Complete Thermodynamic Equilibrium is often constructed - that of Local Thermodynamic Equilibrium (LTE).

In  this  equilibrium  the  atoms  adopt state  populations  given  by  the  Boltzmann  distribution  but  the  radiation is not  necessarily  thermal. In other words, it is possible to find a common temperature, which may vary from place to place, that fits the Boltzmann and Saha distributions and also the Maxwell distribution for the velocities of the electrons.

The criterion for LTE is that collisional processes must be more important than radiative, so that the shortfall of radiative energy does not matter.

**More precisely, an excited state must have a  higher probability of de-excitation by collision than by spontaneous radiation.**

These last two sentences are from Ann P. Thorne, Spectrophysics (1988), section 13.6.

I didn't study the subject of atomic processes in depth (if anyone could mention a good textbook about it, I would be glad to hear), but the collisional processes I know of are:

1. Collisional excitation - in which the electron is moved to an upper level by collision with a free electron, and
2. Collisional de-excitation - the inverse of the afore mentioned process.

Both of these collisional processes do not result in the emission of a photon.

The other (basic) radiative process I learned about it in introductory astrophysics books are:

1. Photoexcitation - in which the electron is moved to the upper level by absorption of a photon of energy $h\nu$,
2. Interaction of a photon resulting in stimulated emission, and
3. Spontaneous emission of a photon.

But a laboratory plasma (studied under the LTE model) does have spectra. Then, what is the source for this light emitted from it? Is it this last process (3)? But "excited state must have a higher probability of de-excitation by collision than by spontaneous radiation", so that process (3) is not the dominant one.

Is there a collisional process that does emit light? Is this collisional process (that I probably haven't heard of) is the dominant one in LTE model plasma? Maybe recombination due to collisions?

If it helps, this is a list of processes that I saw in I. H. Hutchinson - Principles of Plasma Diagnostics (2002), section 6.2:

Radiative:

1. Transitions  between  bound  states.

2.Free-bound transitions:  recombination/photoionization.

Collisional

1. Electron  impact excitation/deexcitation.
2. Impact  ionization/three-body recombination.
3. Dielectronic  recombination/autoionization.

I am familiar with the first 2 (bound-bound and free-bound) but don't have a picture in mind of the last 3. Googling up these queries wouldn't give a concise explanation.

Comment: Are you asking about thermal emission or specific excitations due to recombination or liberation of electrons?

Comment: @honeste_vivere about the second.